# Maven built JAR file doesn't construct JPanel class

Tags: java, maven, jar, jframe, jpanel

I'm currently working on a large, personal project to get even better in Java and to have a project in my CV. I work in IntelliJ IDEA, if that's of any use for this problem.

For this project, I use Maven to structure the project, import dependencies and of course build JAR files. However, I have a problem with that: my code seems to stop after a certain line.

If I run my program in IntelliJ, it works completely fine. On the other hand, if I run my program via a built JAR file, it suddenly stops, at the construction of a JPanel class.

For debugging purposes, I've added logging and I included both logs: one is the full log like it should be when ran from IntelliJ, the second log is generated from running the JAR file. Due to the placement of these log entries, I can see exactly where my code stops functioning in the JAR file.

Both log files are here: http://pastebin.com/L2mBQEDs

[image: Code Screenshot]

```
public MainFrame() {
    LogUtil.logError("Frame", "Frame constructor");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Cinema scheduler " + StringUtil.VERSION);
    setSize(1000, 1000);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 1000));
    setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    LogUtil.logError("Frame", "Test log 1 (before panel construction)");
    MainPanel panel = new MainPanel(this);
    LogUtil.logError("Frame", "Test log 2 (before content pane)");
    setContentPane(panel);
    LogUtil.logError("Frame", "Test log 3 (after content pane)");
    setUndecorated(true);

    FrameDragListener fdl = new FrameDragListener();
    addMouseListener(fdl);
    addMouseMotionListener(fdl);

    setVisible(true);

    LogUtil.logError("Frame", "Frame loaded.");
}
```

I have no idea what's the problem with this. If anyone has any idea what's wrong, that would be great.

Comment: Please post the code of the constructor of `MainPanel`.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/6MNcUrxn Here is the MainPanel class.

Comment: Nothing conspicuously wrong so far for me. But maybe you can insert more log lines to narrow even further the problematic place within the code?!

Comment: Yes, it goes a little further. In the MainPanel, a new WindowsMenuPanel gets constructed. It seems to have a problem with the WindowsMenuButtonGroup. Menu: http://pastebin.com/mjka6Mds (last debug is line 27, so error on line 28 and onwards). ButtonGroup: http://pastebin.com/AJAKjJuh (first log on line 21 doesn't get called)

Comment: Ok, in that class you use foreign libraries (e.g. `jiconfont-swing`). I would expect a log output something like "class not found" but you didn't say that. Nevertheless I expect the problem to be missing jiconfont-swing.jar in your jar or within the classpath. At this jar to your classpath or google for "jar-with-dependencies", so that maven will build a jar with the other jar(s) included.

Comment: Thanks, got it working now.